# Unable to list the files using RestAPI in Databricks

Tags: azure, powershell, databricks, azure-databricks

I am admin of databricks workspace, created PAT token to make API call but continue to get unauthorized access error while trying to check if a folder exist or not using the below code

```
$token = 'MYPAT'
$folderCheckUrl = "$workspaceUrl/api/2.0/dbfs/list?path=$RemoteFolderPath"
$folderListResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $folderCheckUrl -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $token" } -Method GET
```

Any suggestion what's going wrong here?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fmarketplace-extensibility%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops&tabs=Windows I may be wrong but PAT != Bearer. Use $cred =  get-credential and -credential $cred

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general you will receive `Unauthorized access` error when right credentials or enough permissions are not provided for the token. I have used the same script as yours and could able to retrieve the desired results after directly generating my token from `databrick's User Settings >> Access tokens >> Generate new token >> Generate`.

[image]

Make sure you are pointing to the right folder. Below is the complete script that I worked for me to retrieve files from databricks.

[image]

```
$workspaceUrl = '<WORKSPACE_URL>'
$RemoteFolderPath = 'dbfs:/FileStore/tables'
$token = '<GENERATED_TOKEN>'
$folderCheckUrl = "$workspaceUrl/api/2.0/dbfs/list?path=$RemoteFolderPath"
$folderListResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $folderCheckUrl -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $token" } -Method GET
$folderListResponse
```

Results:

[image]

**Note:** I have contributor role for my databricks workspace

Comment: I am following the exact same steps but somehow I keep getting the error {"error_code":"403","message":"Unauthorized access to Org: XXXXXXXXXXXX"} 

I am workspace admin and generated PAT exactly same way as you showed in your screenshots but i am not sure about level of access I have in Azure, is it necessary to have access to workspace in Azure?

Comment: I had firewall blocking the access there was no issue with the code or token.